# Testing a controller ASP.NET ApiController

Tags: asp.net, iis, c#-4.0, asp.net-apicontroller

I just started to built my first API and I wanted to see if it works, so I built a simple test controller and when I try to test it, I get a 404 error.

```
 namespace LoginController
{
    public class TestController : ApiController 
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "Works";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using this url: http://localhost:XXXXX/api/test
what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: i think it has to with the name of your function. try changing it to something else.

Comment: I tried on a different computer and it works fine. I think it has something to do with my configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added the route. 
As in the official documentation 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: but shouldn't this route be added by default in the project? also trying the same project on different computers where it is working with the same configuration, doesn't make sense

Comment: It depends on which instance HttpConfiguration used.
You can clarify this question by looking at the debugger Routes property of class HttpConfiguration.